# How to Copying Range from Google Sheet to Clipboard UIPath

Tags: uipath, rpa, uipath-studio, uipath-robot, uipath-orchestrator

I want to Copying Range from my google sheet to Clipboard using UiPath Studio. Do you guys have any idea how to do this??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found the solution for my own question. Hope it'll help you guys

```
String.Join(Environment.NewLine,(From r In Datatable Select r.item("Column Name"))
```

If you have another solution, you can feel free to answer again.